# Regular expression, specify a number of loops

Tags: javascript, regex

This regular expression looks for words with 3 or less characters so that a non-breaking space can be placed in before them.

```
smallwords = /(\s|^)(([a-zA-Z-_(]{1,2}('|’)*[a-zA-Z-_,;]{0,1}?\s)+)/gi, // words with 3 or less characters
```

Is there a way, to make the expression only apply itself to 2 words in a row?

### Example

Currently, the string:

```
Singapore, the USA and Vietnam.
```

will be turned into:

```
Singapore,&nbsp;the&nbsp;USA&nbsp;and&nbsp;Vietnam.
```

if the expression only applied to 2 words in a row it would show

```
Singapore,&nbsp;the&nbsp;USA and Vietnam.
```

here's the full script:

```
ragadjust = function (s, method) {

    if (document.querySelectorAll) {

            var eles = document.querySelectorAll(s),
                            elescount = eles.length,

                            smallwords = /(\s|^)(([a-zA-Z-_(]{1,2}('|’)*[a-zA-Z-_,;]{0,1}?\s)+)/gi, // words with 3 or less characters

            while (elescount-- > 0) {

                    var ele = eles[elescount],
                                    elehtml = ele.innerHTML;

                    if (method == 'small-words' || method == 'all') 

                            // replace small words
                            elehtml = elehtml.replace(smallwords, function(contents, p1, p2) {
                    return p1 + p2.replace(/\s/g, '&#160;');
                });


                ele.innerHTML = elehtml;

            }
    }
};
```

This is from [RagAdjust](https://github.com/nathanford/ragadjust/blob/master/js/ragadjust.js)

Comment: You're in javascript, right?  and passing this RegExp to the replace function?

Comment: I've just added in the extended script. Thanks for the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not what you are asking for, but I figured a code review wouldn't hurt:

- I think the word boundary `\b` is better, in this case, than `\s|^`.
- You have the `A-Z` and `a-z` characters in your match, yet you are use the `i` case insensitive operator.
- `{0,1}?` is redundant - either use the `?` to make it optional, or use `{0,1}` to make it match zero or one times.
- If your are going to have a dash in your character set put it at the end so that you don't have an ambiguous regex, for example this `[a-z_-]` is much better than `[a-z-_]`.
- If you don't need to capture a value, use the non-capturing parenthesis `(?:)`.

So, here's your cleaned up regex:

`/\b((?:[a-z_(-]{1,2}(?:'|’)*[a-z_,;-]?\s)+)/gi`

I'm pretty sure the `'|’` bit is some sort of typo when you pasted this in from your editor.  Not sure what it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite solve the issue the way you suggested but it does reduce the number of non breaking spaces that end up in the string.   But it might give you some insight.  Because you have the trailing `g` on both regex replacements, you're doing global replace.  If you instead loop it with some max number of fixes, things work out a little differently.

Try changing the max number of replacements.  I think the other thing that happens here (in my modified code) is that after you make one replacement, the spaces and small words are gone because you jammed in a `nbsp` which may or may not solve the issue you're trying to get around.

Here's my replacement function (simplified from your original). The basic mod is to remove the `g` from the regex's and add the loop. You should check out the codepen to see the full deal

```
var new_ragadjust = function (contents) {

  MAX_NUMBER_OF_REPLACEMENTS = 5;

  smallwords = /(\s|^)(([a-zA-Z-_(]{1,2}('|’)*[a-zA-Z-_,;]{0,1}?\s)+)/i; // words with 3 or less characters

  var ii = 0;

  var c = contents;
  for (;ii < MAX_NUMBER_OF_REPLACEMENTS; ++ii) {
    c = c.replace(smallwords, function(contents, p1, p2) {
      return p1 + p2.replace(/\s/, '&#160;');
    });
  }
 return c;
```

};

Codepen
http://cdpn.io/DKLtc

Also, to see the difference, you need to inspect elements to actually see where the `nbsp`s end up (as you probably already knew).